# Enviroment variables in node application

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

while developing my app i've been using the dotenv package to fake enviroment variables.

```
require('dotenv').config({path : '../../../config/.env'});
const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
```

What will happen when i push to my live server with these? How will I handle the enviroment variables then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

On the production server only, set an environment variable named `ENV_PRODUCTION`. Then check for it.

```js
    // save current environment
    const saveEnv = process.env;

    // load local environment
    require('dotenv').config({path : '../../../config/.env'});

    // restore production environment
    if (process.env.ENV_PRODUCTION) {
      process.env = saveEnv;
    }
```